# When Apache Cassandra scheduled repair becomes necessary operational practice?

Tags: cassandra

Like eventual consistency, scheduled repair seems eventually useful from nodes drifting away too much from other.
Trying to understand why and when "Scheduled Repair" becomes mandatory. We are relatively new to operating Cassandra and progressively adopting it. Despite there are no scheduled repairs configured, few services are working quite well for months.
Hence, Have few questions about repair?

1. What is the statistical evidence that developer reliably look at, so
   he/she can understand the immediate or eventual benefit of repair
   processes?
2. Is there any indicator (from log or metrics) that warns
   ahead of time about need of repair?
3. If we build read-heavy (very
   rare transaction) reference data system, do we still need to repair
   regularly?
4. Mistakenly if material-views used in application, should
   we abstain repair till we re-write applications without material-views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple -- repair is part of the normal operation of Cassandra.

There are no metrics/statistics/indicators that determine when to run repairs. You just have to run repairs once every `gc_grace_seconds`. It's as simple as that.

By default, GC grace is 10 days so for simplicity you should run repairs at least once a week if you're not using automated tools like [Reaper](https://github.com/thelastpickle/cassandra-reaper) -- the free, open-source tool for automated Cassandra repairs. Cheers!

Comment: Dropped mutations are one way to find the necessity of repair. If there are zero dropped mutations (or zero delete), we don't need repairs.

Comment: That's not quite correct. The best practice is to always run a repair once every `gc_grace_seconds`. If there's nothing to repair, it will be a no-op. Unless you are an expert in Cassandra and completely know all the little things that go on in your cluster, you need to run repairs. Even engineers who have been working on Cassandra clusters for years follow the best practices. Cheers!